# How to upgrade Android 2.3 to 4.0 on ARM 11 based Tablet?

Tags: operating-system, arm-processors

I have tablet which has a **IAMPX200** Processor and a **M718** Main Board.

The current OS is **Android 2.3**, and I want to upgrade it to **Android 4.0**. Is it possible? If yes, please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

ICS requires an Armv7 processor. Arm11 processors are armv6, as such your tablet doesn't support ICS.

however, a ROM maker may have ported it to your professor and hardware - I suggest you check forums such ad XDA Developers.

Comment: Then on My **ARM11** processor which Android version is supported on `armv6`

Comment: Arm11 is Armv6, ich supports all versions less than 4.0.

Answer (score -2):

What tablet? Some can be updated by going settings>about>software update and follow the prompts!

Or if you can't update that way you have to force up via a program on a computer, I recommend uberoid.

Comment: Down voted as no research made. If you had made some research, you would've seen that ICS isn't compatible with processors of Arm11 architecture.